# What is the fastest way to generate lots of XML data?

Tags: java, xml, xml-serialization

I'm working on a Java utility that generates a bunch of XML documents matching a specific DTD using slightly randomized layout generation (so, for example, the document might look like `<a><b><c /></b></a>` or it might look like `<a><b/><b><c>text</c></b></a>`.

Right now, I've gotten it to the point where I can generate roughly 32,000 documents per second (storing the files in /dev/shm/), and I feel like that's pretty good, but it leaves me wondering if maybe I could do it faster in C++ or maybe some other language with super-fast XML generation. Any contenders?

Comment: What would anyone want with 32,000 documents a second?  Impressive but leaves me wondering what this could be for.

Comment: Testing, almost certainly. Although at that I'd probably find a way to generate them on the fly from Junit and send them to the XML parser under test directly.

Comment: Have you profiled your code to identify where the bottleneck is?

Comment: Yes, I'm generating datasets as input for testing a different program. Profiling doesn't show any useful information - I don't have any obvious bottlenecks here.

Answer (score 0):

As for speed probably not.  You are most likely bound by hard disk speed at that point.  Be sure you are using a buffered class to write to the disk, but otherwise I don't know if it'll get a lot faster.

You could run different threads/instances if you had two hard drives--but writing 2 streams to one drive only slows things down.

Comment: I mentioned in the question that I'm generating data in /dev/shm - this writes files directly into memory instead of onto disk, so I'm absolutely not being limited by disk speed.